# Is it able to read GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENTi in the default framebuffer?

Tags: opengl, render

I searched the whole Internet . People only talk about how GL_FRONT and GL_BACK are not used for FBOs . But for the default FBO , I didn't find much things about if GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 is automatically redirected to GL_FRONT , or if GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1 is redirected to GL_BACK . Is it allowed to call GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENTi for the default FBO ? I supposed GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 will be auto redirected to GL_FRONT but for others , glReadBuffer would simply return blackness .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[glDrawBuffer](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawBuffer.xhtml)

> *buf*
>
> For **default framebuffer**, the argument specifies up to four color buffers to be drawn into. Symbolic constants GL_NONE, GL_FRONT_LEFT, GL_FRONT_RIGHT, GL_BACK_LEFT, GL_BACK_RIGHT, GL_FRONT, GL_BACK, GL_LEFT, GL_RIGHT, and GL_FRONT_AND_BACK are accepted. The initial value is GL_FRONT for single-buffered contexts, and GL_BACK for double-buffered contexts. **For framebuffer objects**, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT$m$ and GL_NONE enums are accepted, where $m$ is a value between 0 and GL_MAX_COLOR_ATTACHMENTS.
>
> **Errors**
>
> - GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if the default framebuffer is affected and none of the buffers indicated by buf exists.
> - GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if a framebuffer object is affected and buf is not equal to GL_NONE or GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT$m$, where $m$ is a value between 0 and GL_MAX_COLOR_ATTACHMENTS.

See also chapter [17.4 Whole Framebuffer Operations](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf#section.17.4) in the OpenGL specification.

Furthermore in chapter [9.1 Framebuffer Overview](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf#section.9.1):

> For the default framebuffer, the color buffers are the front left buffer, the front right buffer, the back left buffer, and the back right buffer.
>
> ...
>
> Framebuffer objects are not visible, **and do not have any of the color buffers present in the default framebuffer**. Instead, the buffers of an framebuffer object are specified by attaching individual textures or renderbuffers to a set of attachment points

Furthermore in chapter [9.2 Binding and Managing Framebuffer Objects](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf#section.9.2):

> Framebuffer objects (those with a non-zero name) differ from the default framebuffer in a few important ways. First and foremost, unlike the default framebuffer, framebuffer objects have modifiable attachment points for each logical buffer in the framebuffer.
>
> ...
>
> Additionally, when rendering to or reading from an application created framebuffer object,
>
> - The only color buffer bitplanes are the ones defined by the frame-
>   buffer attachment points named COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 through COLOR_ATTACHMENTn.

**In short:** there is no such redirection from default framebuffer to framebuffer object attachment points or vice versa. As described above, such attempt in redirection would result in an error.

For completeness, see also chapter [18.2 Reading Pixels](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf#section.18.2).

Answer (score 1):

There is no "default FBO". There is a [default framebuffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Default_Framebuffer), but this is explicitly not an FBO (its name is 0) and default framebuffers have their own rules and buffer names. If you use an API to manipulate framebuffer state, you must use the correct name for the kind of framebuffer you're talking about. If it's an FBO, you use FBO names like `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENTi`. If its a default framebuffer, you use a [different set of names](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Default_Framebuffer#Color_buffers).

There is no mapping between them. If you use the wrong kind of name for the framebuffer in question, you get a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error.